# How to export headings without keywords and progress cookies?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Consider the following file:

```
* My Book
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil
#+OPTIONS: num:nil
** DONE chapter 1 [2/2]
content...
*** DONE section 1.1
*** DONE section 1.2 
** DONE chapter 2 
** TODO chapter 3 
** superseded  :noexport:
```

I place my point at the top heading (My Book) and press `C-c C-e C-s l o`

This produces a pdf file with the following headings:

```
DONE chapter 1 [2/2]
content...
DONE section 1.1
DONE section 1.2
DONE chapter 2
TODO chapter 3
```

However, I want the exported pdf file to look like this:

```
chapter 1
content...
section 1.1
section 1.2 
chapter 2 
chapter 3
```

I tried to use the option `#+OPTIONS: tasks:nil` with the effect that the DONE headings are not exported at all.
Ideally, I could choose that the DONE keyword should not be exported with the heading, while e.g. the TODO keyword should be exported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
#+OPTIONS: todo:nil stat:nil
```

The full set of options is described in the manual in the section [Export Settings](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html). You can read that section in Emacs as well with `C-h i g(org) RET m export settings RET`.

The relevant snippets are:

```
‘stat’
     Toggle inclusion of statistics cookies
     (‘org-export-with-statistics-cookies’).

...
‘tasks’
     Toggle inclusion of tasks (TODO items); or ‘nil’ to remove all
     tasks; or ‘todo’ to remove done tasks; or list the keywords to keep
     (‘org-export-with-tasks’).
...
‘todo’
     Toggle inclusion of TODO keywords into exported text
     (‘org-export-with-todo-keywords’).
```

You can use

```
#+OPTIONS: tasks:todo
```

to exclude DONE *tasks*, but AFAIK, you cannot select *which* TODO *keywords* should be exported: it's all or nothing.

Do `C-h v org-export-with-tasks` for more information on this variable and similarly for `org-export-with-todo-keywords` and `org-export-with-statistics-cookies` for the others.

EDIT: the syntax for setting `tasks` to a list of keywords is

```
#+OPTIONS: tasks:("TODO" "WAITING")
```

But I had to do a bit of trial-and-error; I didn't find it in the docs.

Comment: Thank you NickD. The manual mentions in the 'tasks' section that one could list the keywords to keep. How would one list them?

Comment: Edited the answer with the additional info.